# how to create and connect a storage content in firebase for flutter app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Well, I made a flutter application that contains some svg images  that can be interacted with by clicking on the region, and its name appears (such as the map of the United States of America)
I want to put this content in firebase.
the user should conect  to show the content stocked in firebase
any way or example to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `firebase_storage` package for that

1. In console.firebase.google.com select you project/create project and enable storage.
2. Add package `firebase_storage` in pubspec.yaml, find the latest version on pub.dev
3. In your flutter project use these function

```
StorageReference storageRef =FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('assets/images/myImage.jpg'); // put your images in assets folder and specify the path in the child

StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putData(imageData);// creating the reference and uploading the image to firebase

uploadTask.onComplete.then((value) {
  print('Image uploaded successfully');
}); // When image is uplaod it will print on the console...
```